# Cómo consumir API externa desde Spring con seguridad básica?

Tags: spring, rest

Necesito consumir un API externa para que me devuelva comentarios de ahí.

Me dan el usuario y contraseña y que el H sea `application/json`. Ahora, como puedo combinar esos 3 datos y enviarlos en la request para obtener la respuesta del server? Intenté con `restTemplate.getForObject()` pero no logro resolverlo porque ahí no puedo enviar el user y password.

```
HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
header.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
```

He intentado setear el header con HttpHeaders para luego usar .exchange pero me arroja error el header.set?
Que podrá ser?

---

ACA va mi codigo

@RestController
public class TicketRestController {

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;


//HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(usuarioPassword);

@GetMapping("/comments")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public Object getApi() {
    ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://teclab1593636133.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/42/comments.json", Object.class);
    return response.getBody();
    
}
```

}

//el bean

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

public class TicketsCursosApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TicketsCursosApplication.class, args);
}

 @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .basicAuthentication("url.edu.ar", "Abril2021*").build();  
    }
```

}

Comment: Otra opción es realizar una petición con curl `curl --user usuario:contraseña http://www.miurl.com` si recibes la el mismo error, lo más probable es que las credenciales que utilizas no sean las correctas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer para configurar la seguridad básica es crear un `RestTemplate` a nivel global con un `@Bean` para que todas tus inyecciones del template ya la tengan cargada, te dejo un ejemplo que puedes aplicar:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BasicRestTemplateApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BasicRestTemplateApplication.class, args);
    }

    // Con este Bean sobrescribimos la seguridad del RestTemplate que existe por defecto
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        // Configuración de autenticación básica
        return builder.basicAuthentication("usuario", "contraseña").build();  
    }

}
```

Ten en cuenta que si no quieres que los valores de usuario y contraseña estén visibles en el código los puedes inyectarlas utilizando `@Value("${USUARIO:valorPorDefecto}")` y leerlas desde un archivo, línea de commandos o el sistema.

Un ejemplo simple de de uso seria:

```
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Service
public class MiServicio {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public MiServicio(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public void transaccion() {
        String url = "http://";
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Object.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bien entiendo que así es para precargar los datos de autenticación. Cual es el método que debo llamar en mi controlador? intente con .exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, Object.class); pero me devuelve 401

Comment: He editado mi respuesta con un ejemplo, no es necesario utilizar el método `exchange`, este método se utiliza para tener mayor control sobre los datos de envió, pero si es una consulta `GET` lo puedes sustituir por `getForEntity`, te dejo el ejemplo con Object ya que no especificas la estructura del objeto repuesta, ten en cuenta que la respuesta se obtiene de  `response.getBody()` que te retornara un `Object` que podría ser de tipo `Map<String, Object>` o una lista de `List<Map<String, Object>>`, Lo mejor es que utilices un objeto con la estructura.

Comment: Me arroja un 401. Pongo mi código para mi no envía los datos para autenticar algo estoy implementando mal.

Comment: Prueba realizar la petición con postman para verificar que las credenciales son correctas.